# AWS IAM Policy to Grant All service permission to specific instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have setup separate IAM users from the root account with various privilege levels and I need provide  all EC2 services access  for 2 specific instances to a particular IAM user

I used AWS policy generator and got the below policy but it doesn't work

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Action": "ec2:*",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:instance/INSTANCE_ID",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:instance/INSTANCE_ID"
  ]
}
  ]
}
```

How can I grant permission to the specific instances so the IAM user can only manage those specific instances without accessing any other instances or services.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this via Tags. As stated by the [AWS Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restrict-ec2-iam/), you can try the below policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner": "Bob"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:111122223333:instance/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response i have tried this but last Allow For describe all outsources make every instance visible i tried to overcome it from TAGs but i was unable to do that  `{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Name": "Test"
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: Yes, the user should be able to see those, but they won't have permissions to do any changes.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to hide a set of resources. This is the same scenario for S3 as well. You can grant access to specific buckets, but all will be visible